# Divide dynamic generated form into multiple pages in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, forms

How can I divide one single dynamically generated form to multiple page in angularJs with "required" validation??

Comment: Please provide more details. There is not enough information about your use case to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put each page in one Div and bind that div's visibility to a model variable that will store your current page. Here is Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/ZU7h68iHaFK0k2zSfZhS?p=preview

```
   <form name="myForm">
    <h1>{{currentPage}}</h1>
   <div ng-show="currentPage==1">
       Page1<input type="text" ng-model="page1" ng-required="currentPage==1"/>
     </div>
    <div ng-show="currentPage==2">
        Page2<input type="text" ng-model="page2" ng-required="currentPage==2"/>
    </div>

       <div ng-show="currentPage==3">
       Page3<input type="text" ng-model="page3" ng-required="currentPage==3"/>
     </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" ng-click="NextPage()"  ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" />
    </form>
```

Comment: This will render the whole page, this will make loading the page heavy won't it?

Comment: Depends how much stuff you have in each page and how many pages we are talking about. I guess if we have many big pages, that would be a problem. Then I would suggest do lazy loading and Ajax each page separately. This can be done as part of Next button's handler in the Controller. Each page will initially only have a spinning wheel then.